# Android Paging 3 how do we sync data in background?

Tags: android, android-paging-3

As per [This Android Sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/PagingWithNetworkSample) using `Paging-3` with `RemoteMediator` load function only triggers when then is no more data available, but in Realtime use-cases most of the time list might be updated. So how can we sync that data in background as well as show instant data which is available in DB and later show synced data. As per this sample it will never sync new data until refresh event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onBindViewHolder` adapter method as a signal that your view just got bound to the screen and might be shown to the user, thus, making a request to update that specific item. This approach might also spam your webservice, so be careful.

A diferent approach is to upon the "refresh" signal from Paging 3, delete all items from database at the `RemoteMediator` and start fetching the pages from the network again.

Comment: you did no understand my problem i dont want to delete any item from date I just want to update them. Even if i cached 10 pages those 10 pages should show instantly as well as sync database from network

Comment: That's why I gave you the first alternative, to use onBindViewHolder to update the item shown at the UI. But you should also implement some delay between same requests, so your webservice doesn't get flooded with requests.

Comment: But what I understood from your question is that you want to update the items when they are shown to the user. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Hmm. I just wan to sync that item from server. because Items deatils changes everyday